# How to choose sound device in android

Tags: android, audio, console, usb

I connected usb handsfree to my android device. I need to switch sound input between handfree and built-in microphone. In some devices (like mk802 hdmi-tv-console) threre is system menu where sound input and output could be changed.

I searching a way to change input and ouput from console or from code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any official way of doing what you want. The rationale being something like: if you didn't want to use the handsfree you wouldn't have plugged it in in the first place.

There are a few things you could try, but they're not guaranteed to work across all devices and Android versions.
For playback you could try this to get the audio routed to the loudspeaker instead of the USB accessory:

```
Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
// First 1 == FOR_MEDIA, second 1 == FORCE_SPEAKER. To go back to the default
// behavior, use FORCE_NONE (0).
setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 1);
```

And for recording you could try using the `VOICE_CALL` or `CAMCORDER` `AudioSource` instead of `MIC` or `DEFAULT`.